# Is it possible to specify a fixed minimum size, but no less than min-content?

Tags: css, css-grid

Essentially what I'm trying to do is simply to specify a constraint as:

```
minmax(max(30em, min-content), max-content)
```

**Unfortunately this is isn't valid since `min-content` can't be used in `max` (or `min`). Is there another way to accomplish the same?**

For the actual problem I'm trying to solve, see the below example illustrating how a fixed minimum size and min-content behaves in two different scenarios where the first element is shorter or longer than the ideal:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1ex;
  width: min-content;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  color: white;
}

.first {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: .25ex 1ex;
}

.second {
  width: 2em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.first.longer {
  width: 30em;
}

.container.min-fixed {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(30em, max-content) auto;
}

.container.min-content {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container min-content">
  <div class="first">minmax(min-content, max-content)</div>
  <div class="second">✗</div>
</div>

<div class="container min-fixed">
  <div class="first longer">minmax(30em, max-content)</div>
  <div class="second">✗</div>
</div>

<div class="container min-fixed">
  <div class="first">minmax(30em, max-content)</div>
  <div class="second">✓</div>
</div>

<div class="container min-content">
  <div class="first longer">minmax(min-content, max-content)</div>
  <div class="second">✓</div>
</div>
```